# how to configure Google Engine app.yaml to always resolve to https

Tags: google-app-engine

my current web app resolves/response to both `http` and the `https`. How do I configure my `app.yaml` in a way that it should always resolve the incoming requests to `https` even if the user try forcefully through `http`.

PS: Noob here ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `secure` element as explained in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref) for the paths you want to force https.

> Requests for a URL that match this handler that do not use HTTPS are
>   automatically redirected to the HTTPS URL with the same path. Query
>   parameters are preserved for the redirect.

Example:

```
- url: .*
  script: main.app
  secure: always
```

Comment: For some weird reason, that will redirect to https with a 302 redirect (temporary), you should also use `redirect_http_response_code` to make it a 301 redirect.